# Very strange behaviour when trying to deserialize an object using JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am busy rewriting a web app that was originally written in Angularjs(1.x) and typescript in angular4 and typescript.  I am trying to parse a string representation of a set of `LayoutLines` which for some unknown reason gets stored as a single string value in a row of a database table. For some reason when I `JSON.parse` `items.LayoutData` instead of displaying the lines variable in chrome dev tools as Array(length) it just displays it as (3) {...} {...} {...}.  It does however contain the data so i'm guessing i'm not understanding `JSON.parse` correctly?  Should I be able to map a JSON string to a model using `JSON.parse`?  i'm trying to figure out why the local items variable in `inOnInit` is undefined when i'm assigning it to the LayoutItems object of this.line which isn't undefined?  Otherwise any idea what might be going wrong here/how to go about fixing it? my code/output is below.

the `items.LayoutData` JSON string returned by the back-end looks like this:

```
[{"LayoutLineObj":{"PreLineFeeds":null,"PostLineFeeds":"","LayoutLineItemObjects":[{"LayoutTextObj":{"Text":"asdfgf","TextAttributes":{"Bold":false,"Underline":false,"Italic":false,"FontSize":"single","Align":"left"}}},{"LayoutImageObj":{"ImageUri":"/file","ImageFilename":"f1","ImageSourceType":"http","ImageWidth":"1","ImageAlignment":"center"}},{"LayoutBarcodeFieldObj":{"BarcodeFieldName":"123","Barcode":{}}},{"LayoutTextFieldObj":{"FieldName":"Field1","TextAttributes":{"Bold":true,"Underline":false,"Italic":false,"FontSize":"single","Align":"left"}}},{"LayoutTextObj":{"Text":";lkjhj","TextAttributes":{"Bold":false,"Underline":false,"Italic":false,"FontSize":"single","Align":"left"}}}]}},{"LayoutCommandObj":{"CommandType":{"LineFeedLines":"2","PaperCutPercentage":100,"RenderCommandTypeData":"PaperCut"}}},{"LayoutItemRefGuidObj":"e27534dc-bed3-4f24-84b7-b5c1946305a3"}]

my component code:

    //variable declarations:
    @Input() items: any;
    @Input() lineIndex: number;
    lines: Array<LayoutLine>;
    line: LayoutLine;

    //in ngOninit 
    this.lines = JSON.parse(this.items.LayoutData);
    console.log("lines");
    console.log(this.lines);
    this.line = this.lines[this.lineIndex];
    let items: Array<LayoutLineItem> = this.line.LayoutLineItemObjects;
    console.log("items");
    console.log(items);
    console.log("line");
      console.log(this.line);


the output I get in chrome dev tools console:
lines
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]

items:
undefined

lines
{LayoutLineObj: {...}}
    LayoutLineObj:
        Array(5)
            0: {LayoutTextObj: {…}}
            1: {LayoutImageObj: {…}}
            2: {LayoutBarcodeFieldObj: {…}}
            3: {LayoutTextFieldObj: {…}}
            4: {LayoutTextObj: {…}}
            length: 5
            __proto__: Array(0)
        PostLineFeeds: ""
        PreLineFeeds: null
        __proto__: Object

my LayoutLine model:
import { LayoutLineItem } from './layout-line-item.model';

export class LayoutLine {
    public LayoutLineItemObjects: Array<LayoutLineItem>;
    public PreLineFeeds: number = null;
    public PostLineFeeds: number = null;

    constructor() {
        this.LayoutLineItemObjects = new Array<LayoutLineItem>();
    }          
}

import { LayoutText } from './layout-text.model';
import { LayoutTextField } from './layout-text-field.model';
import { LayoutImage } from './layout-image.model';
import { LayoutBarcodeField } from './layout-barcode-field.model';

export class LayoutLineItem {
    public LayoutText: LayoutText; 
    public LayoutTextField: LayoutTextField; 
    public LayoutImage: LayoutImage; 
    public LayoutBarcodeField: LayoutBarcodeField; 
}

in the previous angular 1.x version lines was deserialized like this:

this.selectedLayoutItem.LayoutItemObjects = angular.fromJson(layoutDef.LayoutData);
```

Comment: What is your specific problem here? It looks like the string is being correctly parsed into an object?

Comment: I am also a bit confused with the question. What is the problem? And where does this this `@Input` come from. A parent apparently, how does that look like?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my LayoutLine model and the JSON data didn't exactly match, I had to add a model with the variable LayoutLineObj of type LayoutLine to have the object mapped correctly...